# Days should display instead of week while calculating the date difference in joda time

Tags: java, date, jodatime, period

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy/MM/dd" ).withZone( timeZone ); 
DateTime dateTimeStart = formatter.parseDateTime("2012/01/01");
DateTime dateTimeStop = formatter.parseDateTime("2017/06/12");
Period period = new Period( dateTimeStart, dateTimeStop );
PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = PeriodFormat.getDefault();

String output = periodFormatter.print( period);
System.out.println(output);
```

Actual Output is: `5 years, 5 months, 1 week and 4 days`

I want output (Recommended) : `5 years, 5 months, 11 days`

Comment: **Read the documentation.** It you did, you'd find [`Period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType type)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard(org.joda.time.PeriodType)). *Down-voting for lack of research.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the manual...

```
Period period = new Period(dateTimeStart, dateTimeStop, PeriodType.forFields(
        new DurationFieldType[]{
                DurationFieldType.years(),
                DurationFieldType.months(),
                DurationFieldType.days(),
                DurationFieldType.hours(),
                DurationFieldType.minutes(),
                DurationFieldType.seconds(),
                DurationFieldType.millis(),
        }));
```